# How to remove the escape characters from web api parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2

I am working on a Web API 2 project written in C#. The post method receives an email from the caller. It gets customerID from the database and sends back to the caller along with the email, in JSON format. When I receive the email it's encoded and looks like, "\"xyz@yahoo.com\"". I tried to remove the backward slash as follows. Still, the JSON looks as shown below. Essentially I want the email in the JSON to be a simple string.

```
 email = email.Replace('\\', ' ').Trim();

JSON:

 {
    "email": "\"xyz@yahoo.com\"",
     "customerData": {
     "customerID": "MAOUOQRM"
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The character `\` is only an escape character for the double quotes after it. So `\"` basically means `"`. The escape character is necessary because JSON-strings are bounded by double quotes themselves.

What this means is that for some reason, your email contains double quotes. The value of `email` in your example is `"xyz@yahoo.com"`.

The best solution would be to find the place where the double quotes get added, because they shouldn't be there in the first place. If you want to remove them, you could do

`email = email.Replace('"', ' ').Trim();`

or just

`email = email.Trim('"');`

which essentially does the same in this case.